# How to create user who will not be using /etc/passwd for authentication?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, users, etc

I want to add a user to my Ubuntu who will be authenticated using SQLite or another database. I don't want to use /etc/passwd file. How can I achieve it?

Comment: http://libnss-mysql.sourceforge.net/configuration.shtml But I'd say use LDAP or AD instead.

Comment: Have a look at PAM modules.